# Sql Join Tables Partial Join Concatenate Results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, concatenation, partial

I have two tables. One has 2 columns - ID, tags.  The tags column is a comma delimited list of tag values.

I the second table, there are also two columns.  One is a list of tags, each in it's own row, and the second column is a label for that tag.

What I need to do is create an output query of each ID, with a semicolon delimited list of the tag labels, for each id that has that corresponding tag value in it's list.

Here is a short example of the two tables:

```
Table1 - 
ID---Tags
1---tag1,tag2,tag3,tag6
2---tag2,tag4,tag5
3---tag3,tag8,tag9,tag10
4---tag1,tag2,tag6
5---tag1,tag4,tag5

Table2 - 
tagname---taglabel
tag1--- Nice Name Tag1
tag2--- Nice Name Tag2
tag3--- Nice Name Tag3
tag4--- Nice Name Tag4
tag5--- Nice Name Tag5
tag6--- Nice Name Tag6
tag7--- Nice Name Tag7
tag8--- Nice Name Tag8
tag9--- Nice Name Tag9
tag10--- Nice Name Tag10
```

Desired result set -

```
ID---TagsNames
1---Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag3,Nice Name Tag6
2---Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag4,Nice Name Tag5
3---Nice Name Tag3,Nice Name Tag8,Nice Name Tag9,Nice Name Tag10
4---Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag6
5---Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag4,Nice Name Tag5
```

I tried to set up a query for an initial join, thinking I could take that results set and concatenate the rows, but I can't seem to get the partial join to work.  Here is that query:

```
 SELECT gt.id as g
      ,gt.tags as tg
      ,tt.HitTagName as ht
      ,tt.termlabel as tl 
FROM tblidtags gt (nolock)
JOIN tbltaglabels tt (Nolock) ON gt.tg like '%' + tt.ht + '%'
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that should actually be JOIN tbltaglabels tt (Nolock) ON tt.ht like '%' + gt.tg + '%' , but it still doesn't work

Comment: I get this error, just to give specifics: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'ht'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'tg'.

Comment: That `tags` column is a multi-value column, which is one of the roots of all evil in SQL.  Don't use them.  You're going to have more problems dealing with that column than anything else.

Comment: I don't have a choice.  This is the way I received the data

Comment: I had to convert the tags column from ntext to nvarchar.  Now I have this SELECT gt.id as g
      ,gt.tags as tg
      ,tt.HitTagName as ht
      ,tt.termlabel as tl 
  FROM tblidtags gt (nolock)
  left JOIN tbltaglabels tt (Nolock) ON tt.HitTagName like '%' + gt.tags + '%' .  It start to run, but then I get the message : Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: @missscripty - You do have a choice on what you do next.  After receiving your data, normalise it, and get yourself out of a hole before you get trapped.  I strongly advise ***not*** propegating the problem further by trying to create yet another set of comma separated values.  It is a seriously painful sql anti-pattern.

Comment: This data isn't going anywhere.  It is a short term, we just need this list translated type of project.  I always design in normalized structures.  For this type of project it will only add time to the process to normalize it first.

Comment: You _probably_ also don't want to be using a text column for the join; usually you want integer columns.  Also, even if that statement was actually returning data, it'd be only one tag-name per row.

Comment: I've posted an answer that returns what you want, but if you can, follow @X-Zero's advice and normalize the table. It's much easier to query against normalized tables.

Comment: Also, next time you ask a question, please make sure your column names (and table names) match between your sample data and any queries you're writing.  Don't abbreviate your table/column names, and don't prefix/suffix them with type information (it's noise).  Oh, your original problem was that your `WHERE` clause used the alias name of the result column, which wasn't 'provided' yet, so it couldn't find the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.ID, b.taglabel FROM
        (SELECT c.ID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Tags FROM 
            (SELECT ID, CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Tags,  ',' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Tag 
                FROM dbo.Table1) c
        CROSS APPLY Tag.nodes('/M') Split(a)) a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 b ON b.tagname = a.Tags)

SELECT ID, STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + NULLIF(taglabel,'') FROM cte t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS tags
FROM cte t1 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID
```

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
    ID tinyint PRIMARY KEY,
    Tags varchar(25))

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2(
    tagname varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    taglabel varchar(15))

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 VALUES
(1, 'tag1,tag2,tag3,tag6'),
(2, 'tag2,tag4,tag5'),
(3, 'tag3,tag8,tag9,tag10'),
(4, 'tag1,tag2,tag6'),
(5, 'tag1,tag4,tag5')

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 VALUES
('tag1', 'Nice Name Tag1'),
('tag2', 'Nice Name Tag2'),
('tag3', 'Nice Name Tag3'),
('tag4', 'Nice Name Tag4'),
('tag5', 'Nice Name Tag5'),
('tag6', 'Nice Name Tag6'),
('tag7', 'Nice Name Tag7'),
('tag8', 'Nice Name Tag8'),
('tag9', 'Nice Name Tag9'),
('tag10', 'Nice Name Tag10')
```

#### Result

```
ID   tags
---- ------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag3,Nice Name Tag6
2    Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag4,Nice Name Tag5
3    Nice Name Tag10,Nice Name Tag3,Nice Name Tag8,Nice Name Tag9
4    Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag2,Nice Name Tag6
5    Nice Name Tag1,Nice Name Tag4,Nice Name Tag5
```

#### Edit 1

To normalize, create another table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id mediumint,
    tag varchar(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tag))

INSERT INTO tags (id, tag) VALUES
SELECT c.ID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Tags FROM 
    (SELECT ID, CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Tags,  ',' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Tag 
        FROM dbo.Table1) c
CROSS APPLY Tag.nodes('/M') Split(a)
```

You can then `JOIN` your `tags` on each `tag`.

#### Edit 2

Look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10386/1) fiddle to see how a normalized schema would look.

Comment: I would be happy to normalize this, but unless there is a programatic way, I am not sure how I can reasonably do this and get this list together.  I don't know how many tags there are in that "tags" column.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Thank you for the query on how to create a new table that is normalized.  I was just looking it up, but it is getting a bit confusing.  I will try to work through your example.  I appreciate everyone's responses.  Sorry if I am a bit slow in responding.  Trying to digest everything.  I am self taught and know what I know, which is to start normalized.  I have a hard time when I run into messes like this, though.

Comment: ok, I have the table normalized.  It is now like this:

ID---tag
1--- Tag1
2--- Tag2
3--- Tag3
4--- Tag4
5--- Tag5
6--- Tag6
7--- Tag7
8--- Tag8
9--- Tag9
10---Tag10

Now, I need to link this to a table that lists each possible tag and a tag label.  Looking at thinks like stuff and group, etc, but they are a bit complex.

Comment: @missscripty Look at edit 2 in my answer to see how a normalized schema and query would work. If this is acceptable, please accept my answer.

Comment: njk, I don't understand this part: from cte t2  WHERE t1.id = t2.id

my two tables need to link on a tag name, not an ID, the way they do in the first part of your solution b.HitTagName = a.tag - also, do I need to change cte to a table name?  Sorry if I am missing the obvious.  I have been working through similar solutions to no avail for hours.

Comment: I have put it together, and I still get 1 row for each label, instead of a concatenated list for each guid/id

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *if* you can, [**normalize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) the table instead of having multi-value columns. This is terrible database design and very hard to query against, as you shall see next.

Now, if you really can't modify the database schema, here's what you have to do:

1. Convert each multi-value column into rows, i.e., `tag1,tag2,tag3` into three rows;
2. For each row, fetch its description from `Table2`;
3. Finally, concatenate all descriptions, grouped by id.

Here's the resulting query and a **working** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b851/2):

```
WITH tmp (id, tag, tags) AS (
SELECT id, LEFT(tags, CHARINDEX(',',tags+',')-1),
    STUFF(tags, 1, CHARINDEX(',',tags+','), '')
FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, LEFT(tags, CHARINDEX(',',tags+',')-1),
    STUFF(tags, 1, CHARINDEX(',',tags+','), '')
FROM tmp
WHERE tag > ''
)
SELECT id, 
 STUFF((SELECT ',' + tbl2.descr FROM tmp INNER JOIN tbl2 ON (tmp.tag = tbl2.tag) 
        WHERE id = a.id
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') tag_names
FROM tmp a
WHERE tag != ''
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

To normalize your schema, you need to create an intermediate table, say, `id_tag(id, tag)`, where `(id, tag)` would form the primary key. Then, you can use the first part (the `tmp` table) of the above query to fill this table. After this, you can remove `Table1`.

Comment: Please don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) - it's been considered an anti-pattern for a while now.  I agree that a recursive query is probably the way to go (to split the tags), but I'm not sure you need `STUFF()` to control the tags you've already encountered - it's actually possible to pass in the various indices (from `CHARINDEX()`) to the next iteration, which should help some performance wise (this is what I have to do in my version of DB2, which lacks `STUFF()`)

Comment: @X-Zero: I agree, it's an habit, many queries written at my workplace use that syntax. I've since edited my answer. I'm not sure about the performance benefits, I'd have to test it, but in a production environment, I'd really try to normalize this schema, instead of actually running this query.

Comment: Oh, no, I agree, the data should be normalized, preferably with numeric ids for the tags, and potentially with the description table being normalizable.